# Adobe Photoshop CS6 crashes dual VGA

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, graphics-card, adobe-photoshop

My Photoshop CS6 crashes when both VGA-s are enabled. If I disable the Intel HD 3000 in Device Manager it works fine.

```
The error:
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: Photoshop.exe
  Application Version:  13.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    4f61c045
  Fault Module Name:    aticfx64.dll
  Fault Module Version: 8.17.10.1230
  Fault Module Timestamp:   52540642
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 00000000000a1a4e
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033
```

Display Adapters:

```
 AMD Radeon HD 7770 (Gigabyte)
 Intel HD 3000 (Core i5)
```

I use both cards, because I have 3 monitors:

```
1 VGA on Intel
2 DVI on AMD 
3 Mini display port on AMD
```

All drivers are up to date, I use 64 bit Windows 7, all updates are installed. Photoshop is also 64 bit. System memory: 16 GB.

When I start Photoshop, Graphics Processor Settings are grayed out (Photoshop detected an error in your display driver.) With Intel HD 3000 disabled it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you're using 2 unrelated graphic cards. You need to use either 1 graphic card, or multiple versions of the *same* graphic card.

> Multiple video adapters can cause problems with GPU-accelerated or
>   enabled features in Photoshop. It's best to connect two (or more)
>   monitors into one video adapter. If you have to use more than one
>   video adapter, make sure that they are the same make and model.
>   Otherwise, crashes and other problems can occur in Photoshop.

[Source](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/photoshop-cs6-gpu-faq1.html#id_97496)

Comment: Very nice Adobe :) I'll have to buy another mini display port->vga adapter and disable Intel HD totally. Or use 2 monitors whenever I use Photoshop.

Comment: @Mart You could also switch Photoshop to [basic rendering mode](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/photoshop-cs6-gpu-faq.html#prefs). Especially if you are not doing anything intensive, I would recommend that. (I was actually researching this recently [laptop with switchable graphics, random PS flickering], and others have said that worked for them.)

Comment: @Bob, this is probably so useful it should be an answer instead of hidden in a comment? The OP never actually asks a question, yet IMO this is a better answer than mine!

Comment: DaveRook I'm actually not 100% sure it will work - the problem this fixes may be a related but not-quite-the-same issue with graphics drivers on Windows 8. It certainly won't hurt to try. (@Mart please let us know if it works! Also try fully disabling GPU acceleration, rather than just basic mode.)

Answer (score 2):

Following on from [Dave Rook's answer](https://superuser.com/a/684785/117590) that Photoshop doesn't really work with multiple GPUs - and this is especially apparent with switchable graphics - you can try to turn GPU-accelerated rendering down to `Basic` or turn it off entirely. There may be a slight performance hit, but as long as you aren't doing anything intensive and/or can afford to wait a bit, this might be preferable over removing a monitor.

To [disable GPU acceleration](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/photoshop-cs6-gpu-faq.html#prefs), untick `Use Graphics Processor` (mentioned in step 2, perform the *opposite* action by *unticking* it). To switch to Basic mode, change the option mentioned in step 3:

> GPU/OpenGL preferences in Photoshop CS6
>
> The advantages of using a compatible video card (GPU) with Photoshop
>   are that you can experience better performance and more features.
>   Problems can occur if you have an older video card with limited VRAM.
>   They can also occur if you use other programs that use the GPU at the
>   same time as Photoshop.
>
> 1. Choose Edit > Preferences (Windows) or Photoshop > Preferences (Mac OS).
> 2. In the Performance panel, make sure that Use Graphics Processor is selected in GPU Settings.
> 3. Click Advanced Settings and specify the following options:
>
>    **Mode > Basic** Uses the least amount of GPU memory and enables basic OpenGL features.
>
>    **Mode > Normal** Uses more GPU memory and enables GPU-based color matching, tone mapping, and checkerboard blending.
>
>    **Mode > Advanced** Provides the benefits of Normal mode as well as newer OpenGL advances that can result in improved performance.
>
>    **Use Graphics Processor to Accelerate Computation**
>
>    **Use OpenCL** Uses the GPU to accelerate the new blur filters (Field Blur, Iris Blur, and Tilt-Shift). OpenCL is only available on newer GPUs that support OpenCL v1.1 or later.
>
>    **Anti-Alias Guides And Paths** Allows the GPU hardware to smooth the edges of drawn guides and paths.
>
>    **30-bit Display (Windows only)** Allows Photoshop to display 30-bit data directly to screen on video cards that support it

Answer (score 0):

seems to be a common issue, I've found this solution as I describe in this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/691128/photoshop-sees-wrong-graphic-card):

I had some similar issue but with the Photoshop crashing all the time with the dual adapters bug and I found a solution that might help you:

1. Before opening Photoshop go to `My Computer > Manage > Device Manager` and disable the Display Adapter that you don't want to use
2. Open Photoshop and check in `Preferences > Performance` if the wanted display is selected.
3. If the Adapter is correctly selected re-enable the disabled one from the `Device Manager`

this is annoying but does the trick.