# Graphic card crashing with photoshop

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, adobe-photoshop, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a new notebook and this machine has two graphics cards.  One is "Intel HD Graphics", and the other one is "GeForce GT 740M".

Since Photoshop has some problems with multiple graphics cards, some configuration in the NVIDIA Control Panel was necessary, and I've set Photoshop to use the NVIDIA card. (See image below)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIVwc.png]
<sup><sub>([Image source](https://superuser.com/a/700913/83694))</sub></sup>

But the problem is that even with this configuration, almost every time that I open Photoshop (very randomly), Windows 8.1 pops up a message saying that the Intel HD Graphics driver has stopped responding and has successfully recovered, even though many of Photoshop's features, such as 3D, are disabled.

So I've tried to disable the Intel HD Graphics driver in Windows Device Manager, and it basically worked out—no more pop up messages and errors—but if I keep this configuration, I cannot use my dual monitor, since the only HDMI socket that I have in this notebook is linked to the Intel HD Graphics card, and I don't want to turn off my other screen just to use Photoshop.

How can I keep both monitors on while using Photoshop without the Intel HD Graphics driver crashing?

Comment: What happens if you run Photoshop by *right-clicking* the icon and using the option to **Run with graphics processor...** and start the program using the NVIDIA graphics card?

Comment: Tried this several times here, and oddly enough the problem seem to be vanished, any idea why?
This option was marked as the default.
I'll keep testing it through this week, if the problem is really gone, i will be glad to favorite your answer.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: I've made my comment an answer. As for the reason this works, all I can say for sure is that this method has always worked more reliably on mobile computers with dual graphics processors than other options. I'm not certain why the control panel option doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 3):

Run Photoshop by *right-clicking* the icon and using the option to **Run with graphics processor...** and start the program using the NVIDIA graphics card. This will properly instruct Photoshop to use the correct graphics card.

You can't *disable* the Intel HD Graphics adapter, per se, since Windows considers it the primary graphics card.  Instead, you selectively run programs with the NVIDIA adapter when you wish to avail that program its better graphics processing, but you do so at the cost of battery life (unless you're on A/C power).